# Loading Textures fast into OpenGL 2.0

Tags: android, opengl-es, textures, opengl-es-2.0

I am building a simple live wallpaper for Android. I am uploading the required texture into OpenGL ES 2.0 using the below code. I have loaded all my images into a single file of size 2048x2048. This below code takes about 900 to 1200 ms to load the texture. Is this a normal time or am I doing something wrong to make it slow?

I also try to clear the list of textures in Opengl every time the onSurfaceCreated is called in my renderer. Is this right to be done, or is there a way to simple check if the previously loaded texture is already in memory and if so avoid clearing and reloading? Please let me know your comments on this. Thank you.

Also on screen orientation change the OnSurfaceCreated is called. So the texture upload happens again. This is not a good idea. What is the work around?

```
public int addTexture(Bitmap texture) {

    int bitmapFormat = texture.getConfig() == Config.ARGB_8888 ? GLES20.GL_RGBA : GLES20.GL_RGB;

    int[] textures = new int[1];
    GLES20.glGenTextures(1, textures, 0);
    int textureId = textures[0];
    GLES20.glBindTexture(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, textureId);

    GLUtils.texImage2D(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, bitmapFormat, texture, 0);
    GLES20.glTexParameterf(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GLES20.GL_LINEAR_MIPMAP_LINEAR);
    GLES20.glTexParameterf(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GLES20.GL_LINEAR);
    GLES20.glTexParameteri(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GLES20.GL_REPEAT);
    GLES20.glTexParameteri(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GLES20.GL_REPEAT);
    GLES20.glGenerateMipmap(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D);
    return textureId;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A few ways you can improve performance.

1. Do not load the texture every time `onSurfaceChanged` is called. Initialize your `textureId` to -1 (in the constructor/surfaceCreated of your renderer) and check at the beginning of `onSurfaceChanged` if you have a different Id. When you call `glGenTextures`, you will get a positive number.
2. Do you need the Mipmaps? That might be the key point of your method here. Try without the line `GLES20.glGenerateMipMap(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D);`
3. 2048x2048 is huge. Especially for textures. Do you really need that much detail? Maybe 1024x1024 is enough.
4. Avoid RGB_888, use RGB_565 instead: you'll get almost the same visual quality for half the size.

Comment: I size 2048x2048 is because i have merged the texture of many items in my application to just 1 file. I can easily split the texture to 4 different 1024x1024 files. But I will have to load 4 different files then. Will splitting this way increase my performance or will it result in increased upload time as i have 4 images to be uploaded now?

Comment: I would say that the upload time will increase if you split the files due to some overhead related to other functions calls, but you might have to try.

Comment: Thank you. I would also like to know if there will be any problem in loading the texture of size 2048x2048? I mean in any old android phones running 2.2 will there be any limitation of image size?

Comment: Think in terms of memory: a 2048*2048*2 bytes (RGB_565) requires 8 MB of memory. The same image with 4 bytes (RGBA_8888) requires 16 MB. That is a lot. You might also look at texture compression http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/opengl.html at "Texture compression support".